# Run shell command on predefined variable using shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Linux. The command to copy to clipboard is `echo "Text"| xsel -i --clipboard`

How can I copy `${fileDirname}` (Predefined variable of vscode) to clipboard with a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following solutions.

[copy-directory-path](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=daniels.copy-directory-path) extension.

Or, using [Command Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edonet.vscode-command-runner).

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+q c",
    "command": "command-runner.run",
    "args": {
        "command": "echo ${fileDirname}/${selectedText} | xsel -i --clipboard",
        "terminal": "runCommand"
    }
}
```

Or,

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+q c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {"text": "echo ${fileDirname}| xsel -i --clipboard \u000D"}

}
```

**Update 1:**

The second solution is not working (at least on my machine) for some reason.